# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" Sql Developer

Tags: database, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to execute following sql code.

```
--1
CREATE TABLE User_Type(
User_Type_ID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
User_Type_Name Char(20 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE User_Type_seq;
CREATE TRIGGER User_Type_ID_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON User_Type
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT User_Type_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.User_Type_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

When I write it by hand to sql developer, it works. But I need a lot of block like this. So, I've edited those with notepad++ and copy/paste to sql developer again. This time; tables and sequences were created but  it gives an error about trigger code (I've taken this routine with select from user_errors)

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ERROR                103 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ;

Here is the full code which doesn't work. create table and sequences codes works, but the trigger code doesn't.

```
--1
CREATE TABLE User_Type(
  User_Type_ID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  User_Type_Name Char(20 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE User_Type_seq;
CREATE TRIGGER User_Type_ID_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON User_Type
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT User_Type_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.User_Type_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
--2
CREATE TABLE Users(
  User_ID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  User_Password Char(8 ) NOT NULL,
  User_Name Char(20 ) NOT NULL,
  User_Type_ID Integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE SEQUENCE Users_seq;
CREATE TRIGGER User_ID_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON Users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT Users_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.User_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
--3
CREATE TABLE Admin(
  Admin_ID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  E_mail Char(20 ) NOT NULL,
  Phone_Number Char(20 ) NOT NULL,
  User_ID Integer NOT NULL
);
CREATE SEQUENCE Admin_seq;
CREATE TRIGGER Admin_ID_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON Admin
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT Admin_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.Admin_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
--4
CREATE TABLE City(
  City_ID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  City_Name Char(20 ) NOT NULL
);


CREATE SEQUENCE City_seq;
CREATE TRIGGER City_ID_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON City
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT City_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.City_ID
FROM DUAL;


/
```

I've searched similar questions but no response to solve my problem.

Sorry for English, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing an `END;` in your final trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER City_ID_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON City
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT City_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.City_ID
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Everything else [is already created and compiled successfully](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ea5d/2).

Incidentally, from 11g you can assign a sequence directly in PL/SQL, withouth having to select from dual:

```
...
BEGIN
  :new.City_ID := City_seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot. Yes, unfortunatelly I've forgotten the "END;", otherwise your code doesn't work on sql developer 3.2 too.

Comment: @jannissary - I've just dug out a copy of 3.2, copied the code from SQL Fiddle, pasted it in to a new worksheet, and it ran OK. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Error starting at line 16 in command: END Error report: Unknown Command. I want to ask that which JDK do you use also which client version of Oracle Database? I've used jdk 1.6.0_45 and 11g

Comment: @jannissary - JDK 1.6.0_35; Oracle 11.2.0.3. I don't see how you can get that error unless you've copied and pasted incorrectly, Or added `END;` after the first trigger in your original code, which isn't what I said to do. Only your last trigger was missing that, and it has to be before the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved. Unfortunately, a letter mistake I have not understood yet why, but:

it must be

```
create trigger
```

instead of

```
CREATE TRIGGER
```

Comment: It isn't case-sensitive, and even if it was it wouldn't explain the error message you got. I think you must have changed something else at the same time. Glad it's working though.